# Can not update task status in celery

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery 4.1.0 with redis and python 3, for executing tasks.

I am running a task chain like this:

```
def identifier():
    res = chain(
    authenticate.s(token),
    get_identifier.s(id_type, amount)
    ).apply_async()

    return jsonify({'task_id': res.id}), 202, {'Location': url_for('task_status', task_id=res.id)}
```

In my `get_identifier` function I have the following else statement, if some conditions are not fulfilled:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def get_identifier(self, authentication, id_type, amount):
if:
    # some stuff
else:
    self.update_state(state=states.FAILURE, meta="result is None")
    return {'StatusCode': '403',
            'error_message': authentication['error_message'],
            'id_type': id_type,
            'identifier': items_list
            }
```

In another function, I am checking for the task status like this:

```
def task_status(task_id):
    task = get_identifier.AsyncResult(task_id)
    print(task.state)
```

The task state is always `SUCCESS` although I expected it to be `FAILURE` in the case when the code enters the `else` statement.

Maybe someone has an idea of what I did wrong here.